# Reputation values on meta and main site are different

Tags: bug, reputation

Back on July 29, I dropped 100 points on a [bounty](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/users/1375/normal-human?tab=bounties&sort=offered), bringing my reputation down to 1. (Hence, I cannot vote or comment on the main site).

Yet, my reputation here on meta is still 101 points, allowing me to upvote and comment.

I know there is some delay when reputation propagates from main to meta, but it's not supposed to be more than a month.

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be, and a quick search of [meta.SE] didn't turn up anything that looked like an answer.  Hopefully an SE employee will see this and have an answer.